# rspec matcher for build in new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, controller

How/with which matcher can I test if `@product.industry_products.build` and the rest are defined in my action?

products_controller

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
  authorize @product
  @product.industry_products.build
  @product.product_features.build
  @product.product_usecases.build
  @product.product_competitions.build
end
```

products_controller_spec.rb

```
context "GET new" do
  let!(:profile) { create(:profile, user: @user) }
  before(:each) do
    get :new
  end

  it "assigns product" do
    expect(assigns(:product)).to be_a_new(Product)
  end

  it { is_expected.to respond_with 200 }
  it { is_expected.to render_template :new }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mocks to check if certain methods are called in your code:

```
expect_any_instance_of(Product).to receive_message_chain(:industry_products, :build).and_call_original
expect_any_instance_of(Product).to receive_message_chain(:product_features, :build).and_call_original
```

These should be declared before the `new` action is called.

However, in my opinion, testing whether certain methods are called isn't all that useful in this example as there's no conditional logic in your controller action. Checking the existence of the associations on product might be a more reliable test.

Comment: Anthony, I have those tests in model spec. So you think in that case it's unnecessary to test if instance variables are set in the controller?

Comment: In this case, yes. If you want to test that they're called just use `expect(assigns(:project).industry_products.size).to eq(1)`. Or, better yet, ensure that the `industry_products` fields actually show up in your form.